# How to get the correct LOD calculation?

Tags: tableau-api

in my dataset there are a few customers who churned besides that their subscription plan information. Customers can change their subscription, so here I get the max plan:

```
{FIXED [Customer Id]:MAX( 
  (IF {FIXED [Customer Id]: MAX(
    IF NOT ISNULL([Subscription Plan]) THEN [Date] END)
        }=[Date] THEN [Subscription Plan] END)
)}
```

To find customer churn:

```
{ FIXED DATETRUNC('month', [Date]), [Max Plan]:
COUNTD(
IF NOT ISNULL([Churn Date]) AND 
DATETRUNC('month', [Date]) = DATETRUNC('month', [Churn Date])
THEN [Customer Id] END
)
```

I want to calculate the revenue loss by churn, i.e. for each customer churn with advanced plan costs 9, for premium 19 dollars.

```
IF [Max Plan] = 'advanced' THEN [Churn]*9 
ELSEIF [Max Plan] = 'premium' THEN [Churn]*19
END
```

However, it doesn't give me the correct result.

[image]

Here is the expected result:

[image]

Here is the workbook attached: https://community.tableau.com/s/contentdocument/0694T000004aUnLQAU

Comment: Given that you have two churns in each, the Tableau totals are correct. But you have totals not averages. Change the aggregation to average and they should be right.

Comment: The file is not downloading? can you upload it on some drive and share link, pl